# How to show glyphicon eye based on value in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have glyphicon-eye for all fields in the form. If user click on glyphicon-eye-open then it will change to glyphicon-eye-close and I push that specific field name into an array.

In my JSON response I am getting the hidden field values but how can I use that value and call exact glyphicon-eye.

**JSON response :**

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": {
      "code": "0",
      "message": "Success"
    },
    "service": {
      "servicetype": "4",
      "functiontype": "1005"
    },
    "data": {
      "session_id": "372",
      "roles": [
        {
        "hiddenfields": [
          {
            "fname": "firstname",
            "fblink": "fblink",
            "country": "country",
            "martialStatus": "martialStatus"
          }
        ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
 $scope.user = {
            fname: "firstname",  
            lname: "lastname",
            dob: "dob",
            gender: "gender",
            country: "country",
            state: "state",
            city: "city",
            pincode: "pincode",
            martialStatus: "martialStatus",
            emailId: "emailId",
            mobile: "mobile",
            qualification: "qualification",
            fblink: "fblink"

        };

        $scope.allow = {};

        $scope.users = [];

        $scope.push = function(){
            $scope.users = [];
            var user = {}, 
                allow = $scope.allow;
            console.log(allow);
          Object.keys(allow).forEach(function(key){
            allow[key] ? user[key] = $scope.user[key] : null;
          });
          $scope.users.push(user);
        }
```

**HTML :**

```
<a class="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="allow.fname"><i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-eye-open':allow.fname, 'glyphicon-eye-close':!allow.fname}" ng-click="push(allow.fname = allow.fname?false:true)"></i></a>
```

If field value is in array then I need to show glyphicon-eye-close.

Comment: 1. The allow.fname isn't that a string? 2. allow.fname = allow.fname?false:true...how will this ever be false? 3. the push method doesn't take any parameters

Comment: Pro-tips for posting here: (1) try to make titles an ordinary question in English, terminating in a query mark (`?`). We would rather themes (such as "AngularJS") are not added in home-made tags at the start or end, we get quite a lot of `Mongo - PHP - question` and `JavaScript | HTML | CSS | question` - use the tagging system for that please. (2) there is no need to add `Please help me` to every single post you do (and, for that matter, comments as well). We know you want help, so any explicit statements to that effect may be read as a form of begging.

Comment: (3) Please do not add any requests for urgency to your posts, this is generally understood to be excessively demanding or rude. Read [more about this here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). (4) Of the 20 questions you have asked, you have accepted just one of them. This rather too low. Please review your old questions and see if there are any answers you can accept.

Comment: (4) your most egregious error is ignoring answers and giving no response at all, in a full half of the questions you have asked so far. **This is unacceptably rude behaviour**. [Take a look at this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38828521) to you, which must have taken an hour to write up, and is complete with a Fiddle too. You may benefit [from reading this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times the ! doesnot works inside ng-clss. You please replace that by

```
<a class="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="allow.fname">
    <i class="glyphicon" 
     ng-class="{'glyphicon-eye-open':allow.fname.length > 0, 'glyphicon-eye-close':allow.fname.length == 0}" 
     ng-click="push(allow.fname = allow.fname?false:true)">
    </i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class like below.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="x in allow" >
      <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-eye-open': x.fname==0 ,  'glyphicon-eye-close': x.fname==1}"></span> {{x.name}}</button>
 </div>
```

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.allow=[{
      'fname':1,
      'name':'Anil'
    },{
      'fname':0,
      'name':'Sunil'
    },{
      'fname':1,
      'name':'Manil'
    }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="x in allow" >
      <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-eye-open': x.fname==0 ,  'glyphicon-eye-close': x.fname==1}"></span> {{x.name}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to glyphicon based on values by assigning the response to my model as below,

```
$scope.allow = response.data.roles[0].hiddenfields[0];
```