# Is there any APK to display all countries, states and cities as dropdown in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to display all countries as a dropdown and based on the country need to display all states of that country. Similarly all cities of the selected state.

Is there any APK or external js file available for this?

Comment: As an editor, one thing I would like to see when I repair questions here is that posters learn from the edits I make, especially if I comment explicitly. So when [I ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40394740) that you refrain from adding please-help begging to every question, and refrain from adding home-made tags to your titles, would you do so?

Comment: Yes I will ensure that this doesn't happen again

Comment: Thank you. Please reply to, and optionally vote upon, Sajeetharan's answer too (I should not have to remind, of course).

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/countries/

You can use this library but it has only countries and States not cities.

Comment: Thank you but I need cities also

Answer (score 0):

My code is working like charm.

I am able to list all the countries and based on countries i am populating states and based on states i am populating cities.

I just used this js file in my html page 
`<script src="http://iamrohit.in/lab/js/location.js"></script>`

refer : http://www.iamrohit.in/city-state-and-country-drop-down/