# How to match the value from response to dropdown list value?

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying all countries, states and cities as a list using an external js file.

If I select any country I am able to choose state of that country and respectively.

But when I try to display country by fetching the country value from response I am getting empty value. In console I saw below code.

```
<option value="? string:India ?"></option>
```

I don't know why my response value doesn't match the external js file.

[Is there any APK to display all countries, states and cities as dropdown in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416220/is-there-any-apk-to-display-all-countries-states-and-cities-as-dropdown-angul/40416392#40416392)

```
<div class="form-group1 col-sm-4">
             <select name="country" class="drop3 countries" required  ng-model="model.country" placeholder="select" id="countryId sel11"><option value='' disabled selected>Country</option>
            <!--<option ng-repeat="item in country track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>-->
                </select>
                        </div>  
                     <div class="form-group1 col-sm-4">        
              <select name="state" class="drop3 states" required  ng-model="model.state" placeholder="select" id="sel21 stateId"><option value='' disabled selected>State</option>
            <!--<option ng-repeat="item in state track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>-->
                </select>

                    </div>  


           <div class="form-group1 col-sm-4">        
                        <select name="city" class="drop3 cities" required  ng-model="model.city" placeholder="City" id="sel31 cityId">
                        <option value='' disabled selected>City</option>
                        <!--<option ng-repeat="item in city track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>-->
                </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It will be hard to help you if there is no code

Comment: where is your js code?

Comment: js is actually a external file and is "http://iamrohit.in/lab/js/location.js"

Comment: Its a link and i mentioned in my above comment

Comment: There isn't any angular code in your js. Looks like you're completely messing up mixing the two.

Comment: js is actually a external file and is "iamrohit.in/lab/js/location.js";