# How to display tab as nav menu with media size in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have three tabs and styling is also done. I need to create a nav menu  with nav-icon after particular media screen size.

When I click on that nav-icon it should show all tabs as list.

I tried to implement nav-bar but it is affecting my tab styling.

**My HTML:**

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-7 main-div" >
            <div  class="main-div1" style="background-color: white;">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" >
                            <li class="tablist" ng-class="tab === 1? 'active' : ''"><a ng-click="changeTab(1)" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>MANAGE PROFILE</b></a></li>
                            <li ng-class="tab === 2? 'active' : ''" style="border-left: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;"><a ng-click="changeTab(2)" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>CHANGE PASSWORD</b></a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-class="tab === 3? 'active' : ''"><a ng-click="changeTab(3)" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>PAYMENT HISTORY</b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" 
                        ng-bind="flash.message" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>

                        <div class="tab" ng-show="tab === 1">
                            <form name="mForm" role="form" data-ng-init="initController" ng-submit="updateProfile()" >
    <!-- form details -->
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" ng-show="tab === 2">
                            <form name="mForm" role="form" data-ng-init="initController" ng-submit="role()" >
    <!-- form details -->
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<!-- style -->

.nav-pills li.active a {
        color: white;
        background-color: #2c0e48;
    }

    .nav-pills li.active a:hover {
        background-color: #6C3483;
        color: white;
    }

    .nav-pills li a {
        color: black;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .tab {
        margin-left: 3em;
        margin-top: 4em;
        margin-bottom: 9em;
        margin-right: -2em;
    }

     .content {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        pointer-events: none;
        margin-left: 0em;        
    }
```

Comment: You can have a look at the example in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp   (the part for 'Collapsing The Navigation Bar').

Comment: A reminder that we prefer titles as they would be asked in English, rather than with home-made tags in them. [My previous note](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40394740/472495) is here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var app = angular.module('main', []);
                        app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
        
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
.nav-pills li.active a {
        color: white;
        background-color: #2c0e48;
    }

    .nav-pills li.active a:hover {
        background-color: #6C3483;
        color: white;
    }

    .nav-pills li a {
        color: black;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .tab {
        margin-left: 3em;
        margin-top: 4em;
        margin-bottom: 9em;
        margin-right: -2em;
    }

     .content {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        pointer-events: none;
        margin-left: 0em;        
    }
</style>

       <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
         <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-7 main-div" >
            <div  class="main-div1" style="background-color: white;">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" >
                            <li class="tablist" ng-class="tab === 1? 'active' : ''"><a ng-click="tab=1" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>MANAGE PROFILE</b></a></li>
                            <li ng-class="tab === 2? 'active' : ''" style="border-left: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;"><a ng-click="tab=2" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>CHANGE PASSWORD</b></a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-class="tab === 3? 'active' : ''"><a ng-click="tab=3" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>PAYMENT HISTORY</b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" 
                        ng-bind="flash.message" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>

                        <div class="tab" ng-show="tab === 1">tab 1
                            <form name="mForm" role="form" data-ng-init="initController" ng-submit="updateProfile()" >
    <!-- form details -->
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" ng-show="tab === 2">
      tab 2
                            <form name="mForm" role="form" data-ng-init="initController" ng-submit="role()" >
    <!-- form details -->
    </form>
    </div>
              
                <div class="tab" ng-show="tab === 3">
      tab 3
                       
   
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

         </div>
```